# Objective-C double Delegate protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates

I get the following error when compiling my app.

> warning: class 'ConfigureViewController' does not implement the 'MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate' protocol

I know that it means I have to implement the delegate in the Controller.
i.e `@interface ConfigureViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate>`

However, my current controller already has a delegate implementation for `<UITextFieldDelegate>`
i.e `@interface ConfigureViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`

How do I go around this issue?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just separate them by a comma: `<MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>`

Answer (score 13):

One can implement multiple protocols by specifying multiple protocols in the class declaration.

In this case, in order to implement both `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate` and `UITextFieldDelegate`, the class declaration would be:

```
@interface ConfigureViewController : UIViewController < UITextFieldDelegate, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate >
```

Comment: Uh oh, that's easier than I thought.
Thanks coobird